# batch if exist multiple files (what if only one doesn't exist)

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I use this line now:

```
IF EXIST "%SystemDrive%\Arkey5" (ECHO Found "%SystemDrive%\Arkey5" >> "LOG.txt" 2>&1) ELSE IF EXIST "D:\Arkey5" (ECHO Found "D:\Arkey5" >> "LOG.txt" 2>&1) ELSE ECHO NOTHING FOUND >> "LOG.txt" 2>&1
```

This works almost perfect, it only misses this one thing, 
if both directories exist I don't get a log line written...
So at this moment only when: 
 01. "%SystemDrive%\Arkey5" exist 
 02. "D:\arkey5" exist 
 03. ELSE (both missing)

Comment: Could you separate it out into 2 lines? and have the possibility of 2 log lines?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: things can be separated, no problems...
purpose = to check if the Arkey5 directoriy exists on systemdrive (C:) and/or D: drive, if so create a log line that it was found and where (C: and/or D:). Now at the moment it's almost perfect, the only flaw now is that it doesn't create a log line if the Arkey-directory exists on both drives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set found=
for %%F in (
  "%SystemDrive%\Arkey5\"
  "D:\Arkey5\"
) do if exist %%F (echo Found %%F >>"log.txt" & set found=1)
if not defined found echo NOTHING FOUND >>"log.txt"
```

Added `\` to end of each path to make sure that IF EXIST only matches a directory.

Comment: @dbenhan: this one only writes a logline if both don't exist, if one or both exist there is no logline written...

Comment: @APOC - No, it writes to the log in 2 places: inside the loop for found directories, and outside the loop if none found.

Comment: @APOC This worked for me. If neither was found, I got `NOTHING FOUND` in the log. If either one was found, I got the name of the folder in the log file. If both were found, I got the both folder names in the log file.

Comment: oops, my bad, I ran the script on a shared network map with insufficient rights, I changed 1 log.txt redirection and I forgot to change the other...stupid stupid stupid... It works like a charm, thank you very much.